# Read four elements from a character array into another character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose `char *data = "02001110000000000"`

How can i move only first four elements `0200` into another character array?

Comment: Did you research that?

Comment: Why do you want to use char array instead of string if you are using C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strncopy`:

```
char *data = "02001110000000000"
char dest[4];
strncopy(dest, data, 4);
```

Note that `strncopy` does not copy the null terminating character (`'\0'`), so `dest` here isn't a string, it's just an array with four `char`s. If you want it to be the string "0200", you'll have to define it as a five-element array and append the `'\0'` character yourself.

Comment: `char *data = "02001110000000000"` is illegal in c++

Comment: @Slava It's deprecated, but not illegal. It should be `const char *`

Comment: @CJxD it was deprecated in c++03, it is illegal now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to *copy* the characters into your new array (i.e. it's acceptable to reuse the same allocated memory), you can do a bit of a pointer trick for this.

An array is just a pointer to the first element.

```
char firstFour[4] = &data[0];
or
char *firstFour = &data[0];
```

To remove the elements from the first array, do

```
data = &data[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

char* newArray = new char[4];

memcpy(newArray, data, 4);

Comment: Ups, what about the terminating `\0`?